# Azure Functions Custom Binding for ClaimsPrincipal / UserProfile

Tags: c#, angular, azure-active-directory, azure-functions

Is there a way to use custom entity to use Azure Functions with Azure Active Directory integration?

I am trying to integrate a simple Angular App and azure function I assumed this would be very straight forward but it is not. At the moment with MSAL, Angular App is sending the Bearer token to azure functions but for local `ClaimsPrincipal` is Admin.

One option is to use `ClaimsPrincipal` as base class and bind the other data in the ctor. But I am not sure if this work also not sure which ctor I have to use from base `ClaimsPrincipal`.

```
public class UserProfile: ClaimsPrincipal
{
    public UserProfile() 
    {
        //load other data
    }
}
```

Another option is completly custom model binding using ClaimsPrincipal as property type.

```
public class UserProfile
{
    public UserProfile() 
    {
        //load other data
    }

    public ClaimsPrincipal Principal {get; set; }
}
```

But not even sure anyof them possible when I tried to look into custom binding It is always `[FromBody] customObj` usage.

Comment: This is still an open issue at [Set ClaimsPrincipal in Custom Binding](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4851)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to add a custom value binding using github for [Azure WebJobs Extentions](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions). Not sure if it is against any rule or principle but working fine for me.

First define your own object to bind let say `UserProfileAD` and copy [ClaimsPrincipalBindingProvider](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/a0fb2011acfa88126d9eecc285d7a7f8283ccbe5/src/WebJobs.Extensions.Http/ClaimsPrincipalBindingProvider.cs) content and update accordingly e.g. change every  `ClaimsPrincipal` to new type and where it sets the value handle your own way. The new BindingProvider (`UserProfileADBindingProvider`) is where you can inject other services so you can access DB for example.

But there is a problem in here every class used in the class is defined as internal so your new class cannot access them so also need to replicate `HttpTriggerAttributeBindingProvider`, `StreamValueBinder`, `ValueBinder`

Also because of another access issue change `IsRequestPayloadReadable` in the `HttpTriggerAttributeBindingProvider` to below.

```
        private bool IsRequestPayloadReadable(HttpRequest request)
        {
            return (request.Body != null && request.ContentLength > 0)
                || (_options != null && string.Equals(request.Headers[HeaderNames.TransferEncoding], "chunked", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        }
```

and in the `Startup` `Configure` method add your new BindingProvider to webjobs services as below;

```
var wbBuilder = builder.Services.AddWebJobs(x => { return; });

wbBuilder.Services.AddSingleton<IBindingProvider, UserProfileADBindingProvider>();
```